# How to remove unnecessary webpage elements when printing

Tags: firefox, printing

Is it possible to remove all the unnecessary elements in a webpage. using firefox or other browsers.
So that when you print you will not see the headers and footer, advertisments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Firefox add-on [**Aardvark**](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&ved=0CBsQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Faddons.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Ffirefox%2Faddon%2F4111%2F&rct=j&q=firefox+aardvark&ei=8Yz_S5z5EImX4gansu3LDg&usg=AFQjCNGZxu7EpP1T_h1LMvxyZHgg82Vl_w) (or from [here](http://karmatics.com/aardvark/))

> To use Aardvark, just right-click on
>   the page and select Start Aardvark
>   from the popup menu. As you move the
>   mouse over the page, you will see a
>   red rectangle around the current block
>   element, along with a label showing
>   its type, and if they exist, its id,
>   class, and style.
>
> You can then press various keys on the
>   keyboard to do things, for instance W
>   to navigate wider (as shown in the
>   image), R to remove the element, I to
>   isolate the element (that is, remove
>   everything else on the page), V to
>   view formatted source of that element,
>   U to undo, Q to quit aardvark, and H
>   for help, that is, a list of the 14 or
>   so available keystrokes.

Comment: its nice but its useless if the page has many "next" on it. You will have to do this for every page

Comment: Install Aardvark and AutoPager together.

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox (with Dom Inspector installed) the unwanted elements can be removed manually by right clicking the element, selecting `Inspect Element` and hitting the <kbd>del</kbd> key.

With [Ubiquity](http://mozillalabs.com/ubiquity/) you can select the element and activate the Ubiquity's `delete` command. This method doesn't necessarily work with background images.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell that I don't frequently need to remove ads?-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Has Firefox changed or am I doing it wrong? I have 15.0.1 on WinXPsp3x86. Right-click has "Delete node" but "DEL" shortcut doesn't work. It would be more convenient.

Comment: As it happens, I don't have Dom Inspector installed any more, but `del` seems to work with Firebug as well.

Answer (score 1):

I could run a list and pretend i use them, but [this link](http://www.techyard.net/7-ways-to-optimize-webpages-to-save-ink/) will give you al you need

> Printee for IE – Printee is a Internet Explorer Addon, that lets you remove unwanted ads from webpages before you print them.You can launch it by clicking on the Printee icon from the toolbar.It supports IE 6/7/8 and works on Windows 2000/2003/XP/Vista.
>
> PrintWhatYouWant – Just enter the URL and a toolbar is available with controls on the left, with options for selection, test size (increase / decrease),image removal,font type etc.You can also remove parts from the webpage by hovering the mouse over the unwanted region, and click to select the region and press “Delete Key” to remove it.You can save the edited page as PDF and HTML.You can also combine multiple web pages – edit & print them as one document.You can access the service in 3 ways,

Answer (score 0):

[The Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/) free bookmarklet might be your friend!

(This bookmarklet updates itself, but I think the folks from css-tricks.com can be trusted.)